# Can not Add font in FPDF

Tags: php, ubuntu, fpdf

Hello I am trying to Add Calibri font to FPDF fonts

I have converted the ttf using encoding cp1252 (was the default)
copied the files into the folder fpdf/font/

add the lines

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/usr/share/php/fpdf/font');
require_once('/usr/share/php/fpdf/fpdf.php');
$fpdf->AddFont('Calibri','','calibri.php');
//$fpdf->AddFont('Calibri','B','calibrib.php');
//$fpdf->AddFont('Calibri','I','calibrii.php');
//$fpdf->AddFont('Calibri','BI','calibriz.php'); //Bold Italic
```

the line `$fpdf->AddFont('Calibri','','calibri.php');`
stops processing all the the lines that comes after
and when commenting the line the php runs to the end
ubuntu 20.04 / php 7.4

Can any one please tell me what encoding should I use?
and how so I set the font path ? or why do my code stops without error

Comment: Have you checked the error log for errors?

Comment: I have checked the log
found 
 Undefined variable: pdf in /var/www/html/
then I rialized I have to add the line
$pdf = new FPDF($orientation,'mm',array($width,$height));
before the AddFont lines
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the ttf file as this is how the FPDF software can store it as a font. So there is no need to convert the file. Use the ttf file you already have and should work. I'm assuming this works the same as the python version of FPDF.